# Endomorphisms of Jacobians of Hyperelliptic Curves taking Exceptional Divisors to Exceptional Divisors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, jacobians

I am trying to find an hyperelliptic curve (say of genus 2) together with an endomorphism $\phi$ of its Jacobian with the property that it sends Mumford reduced divisors of the exceptional form $P-\mathcal{O}$ to divisors of the same form (and not $P+Q-2\mathcal{O}$).

For instance, if $f$ is a morphism from the hyperelliptic curve to itself, then $\phi=f_*$ will have this property. However, such a $f$ must be an automorphism, and therefore $\phi$ has finite order.

My question is: can I find such a $\phi$ which is not a root of unity?

Comment: I may not have understood what you wrote, but:  would such a phi, restricted to the image of Abel-Jacobi, yield a map from the curve to itself?  Such a map cannot have degree greater than 1 once the curve has genus at least 2 (e.g. by Riemann-Hurwitz.)



Comment: Ok great thanks (I am not an algebraic geometer, as you can see, but I get it this far). What about higher genus, say $g=3$, with exceptional divisors (not of the form $P+Q+R-3\mathcal{O}$) being sent to exceptional divisors?